# how do i create a subscribe or join group link in drupal 7?

Tags: organic-groups

I am trying to create a join or subscribe link for groups on my site but i don't know how to go about it (using views). I want to create something similar to this http://www.popsugar.com/community/suggest .

Any suggestions?

Comment: OG has a "subscribe to group" feature, just watch this video tutorial for an introduction to OG: http://modulesunraveled.com/organic-groups

Answer (score 3):

Use the field "Content: Group".